# Windows has triggered a breakpoint error in Visual Studio

Tags: c, matrix

I am making a Numerical Linear Algebra library containing a Matrix struct but I get this error when trying to print an Identity Matrix:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in SciComput.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in SciComput.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while SciComput.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

I would be grateful if anyone could assist me with this. Here's my code:

Main function:

```
void main(void)

{
    Matrix k;

    k=eye(5,5);
    printf("%f",GetElement(k,5,5));
    PrintMatrix(k);
}
```

The Matrix struct (Matrix.c):

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

//Allocation of a Matrix and set to 0
//  Input:  M - Pointer to Matrix
//          m - Number of rows
//          n - Number of columns
//  Output: M - Allocated Matrix
void InitMatrix(Matrix *M,const int *m,const int *n)
{
    M->alloc=1;
    M->rows=*m;
    M->cols=*n;
    M->val=(double *)malloc((*m)*(*n)*sizeof(double));
}


//Deallocation of a Matrix if allocated
//  Input:  M - Pointer to Matrix
//  Output: M - Deallocated Matrix
void DelMatrix(Matrix *M)
{
    if (M->alloc==1)
    {
        M->alloc=0;
        M->rows=0;
        M->cols=0;
        free(M->val);
        M->val=NULL;
    }
}

//Fills in an allocated Matrix with a double val
//  Input:  M - Matrix to be filled in
//          val - the number to fill in the Matrix
//  Output: M - Filled Matrix
void Number(const Matrix *M,const double *val)
{
    int i;
    if (M->alloc==1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<M->cols*M->rows;i++)
            M->val[i]=*val;
    }
}

//Returns the element (i,j) of Matrix M
//  Input:  M - Matrix
//          k - row i
//          l - column j
//  Output: element (i,j)
double GetElement(const Matrix M,const int k,const int l)
{
    int p,m;
    m=M.rows;
    p=(k-1)*m+(l-1);
    return(M.val[p]);
}

//Changes the value of element (i,j) of Matrix M with a double
//  Input:  M - Matrix
//          k - row i
//          l - column j
//          y - double to change element (i,j)
//  Output: Matrix M with element (i,j) changed to double y
void PutElement(const Matrix *M,const int *k,const int *l,const double y)
{
    int p,m,i,j;
    m=M->rows;
    i=*k,j=*l;
    p=(i-1)*m+(j-1);
    M->val[p]=y;
}

//Prints the Matrix M
//  Input:  M - Matrix
//  Output: Printed Matrix
void PrintMatrix(const Matrix M)
{
    int m=0,n=0,i=0,j=0,k,l;
    double d;
    m=M.rows;
    n=M.cols;

    for(i;i<m;i++)
    {
        k=i+1;
        j=0;
        for(j;j<n;j++)
        {
            l=j+1;
            d=GetElement(M,k,l);
            if(d>=0)
                printf(" ");
            printf("%f",d);
            printf("   ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}



//Returns the Identity Matrix I of dimension rowsxcols
//  Input:  rows,cols - dimensions
//  Output: Identity matrix I
Matrix eye(const int rows,const int cols)
{
    Matrix I;
    int i=0;
    double zero=0.0;
    InitMatrix(&I,&rows,&cols);
    Number(&I,&zero);

    for(i;i<rows*cols;i++)
        PutElement(&I,&i,&i,1);
    return (I);
}
```

and the Matrix.h:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

struct Matrix 
{
    double *val;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int alloc;

};

typedef struct Matrix Matrix;

void InitMatrix(Matrix *M,const int *m,const int *n);
void DelMatrix(Matrix *M);
void Number(const Matrix *M,const double *val);
double GetElement(const Matrix M,const int k,const int l);
void PutElement(const Matrix *M,const int *k,const int *l, const double y);
void PrintMatrix(const Matrix M);
Matrix eye(const int rows,const int cols);


#endif
```

Comment: Why do `InitMatrix` and `Number` take their primitive-type arguments by pointer instead of by value?

Comment: To be honest I have made this Struct with the help of a much more experienced programmer, he decided to code it that way. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: It's uselessly confusing, adds unnecessary clutter to each access to these variables, and *might* cause a slight performance penalty due to the added level of indirection.

Comment: I am quite new at programming and i find your words interesting, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: In short: `M->rows = m;` is easier to read than `M->rows = *m;`, and you don't need more since the `InitMatrix` function does not modify `m` nor `n`. And it works faster, since the processor has one less memory access to do.

Comment: `void main(void)` is wrong. `int main(void)` is not wrong.

Comment: use `_ASSERTE(_CrtCheckMemory());` before and after each function call. This will guide you to the critical spot immediately.

Comment: Visual studio prompts me with an error saying those functions aren't defined, _ASSERTEE and _CrtCheckMemory

Comment: `#include <crtdbg.h>`

Comment: Oh thanx! Now how do I run it? Would Start Without Debugging give me the results I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can't seem to decide if your matrix should be zero-indexed or one-indexed. `GetElement()` and `PutElement()` are written to expect the lowest coordinates to be {1, 1} (and perform no checks), but `eye` calls them with values that start at zero.

Comment: The problem was the limit of i inside the loop plus the initial value.

Comment: The eye function is correct now thank you very very much. But now that I use it with other functions it throws me a heap problem error:Windows has triggered a breakpoint in SciComput.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in SciComput.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

Comment: If you have changed the eye() function and left the 1 offsets in Get and Put you have not fixed the problem and it will still crash.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm may have been translated from a language (or maths) in which array subscripts start at 1. In C, they are expected to start at 0.

In GetElement:

```
p=k*m+1;
```

Or replace the whole function by:

```
return M.val[k * M.rows + l];
```

In PutElement:

```
p=i*m+j;
```

But the whole function could be replace by:

```
M->val[i * M->rows + j] = y;
```

This error is enough to cause the crash, but there may be others I've missed.

Comment: Well on paper the first element of a Matrix is {1,1} but in C it is the {0}, so I thought of a function that could map this relation from {1,1}->{0}, it works fine as I programmed it. But the problem has something to do with memory as Visual Studio prompts me in Debugging mode, that's why I tried ti seek help from someone much more experienced.

Comment: The problem has little or nothing to do with memory. It's wrong code and wrong index subscripts. If you write outside the bounds of an array or object you will corrupt memory and get errors like this.